# Multiple-parameter Schrödinger equation, such $U(\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\lambda_3)=e^{ -i \lambda \cdot \sigma }$

Tags: quantum-mechanics, schroedinger-equation

One can derive the Schrodinger equation as follows:

$U(\delta t)|\psi(t)\rangle  = (I - i \delta tH)|\psi(t)\rangle = |\psi(t+\delta t)\rangle  \rightarrow i\frac{|\psi(t+\delta t) - |\psi(t)\rangle}{\delta t} = i\frac{\partial |\psi(t)\rangle}{\partial t} = H|\psi(t)\rangle$

---

In the above case, we have taken $U(t)=e^{-itH}$.

Is there value in applying to the same logic but to a unitary operator which may have more that one variable such as $t$. For instance, the SU(2) group:

$$
U(\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\lambda_2)=e^{-i(\lambda_1\sigma_1+\lambda_2\sigma_2+\lambda_3\sigma_3)}
$$

Can we apply the derivation for the Schrödinger equation but for $U(\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\lambda_2)$ instead of $U(t)$? I would like to do it by myself, but I am not sure how to start off the process. Do I vary all three lambdas at the same time, or just one?

$$
U(\delta \lambda_1, \delta \lambda_2,\delta \lambda_3)|\psi(t)\rangle \quad \text{or} \quad U(\delta\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\lambda_3) \quad \text{?}
$$

Then, at the next step, do I get a directional derivative?

$$
U(h\Delta \lambda_1, h\Delta \lambda_2,h\Delta \lambda_3)|\psi(t)\rangle = |\psi(\lambda_1+h\Delta \lambda_1,\lambda_2+h\Delta \lambda_2, \lambda_3+h\Delta \lambda_3)\rangle = (I-ih \Delta \lambda \cdot \sigma)|\psi(\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\lambda_3)\rangle\\
\implies \frac{|\psi(\lambda_1+h\Delta \lambda_1,\lambda_2+h\Delta \lambda_2, \lambda_3+h\Delta \lambda_3)\rangle- |\psi(\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\lambda_3)\rangle}{h}=-i\Delta \lambda \cdot \sigma |\psi(\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\lambda_3)\rangle
$$

Is this the way to get a physically meaningful equation using different definitions of U, that include multiple parameters for the evolution?

Comment: You vary the $\lambda$’s independently; you basically get an expression for the infinitesimal generator $\sigma_i$.  Unless the kinetic and/or potential depend on the $\lambda$’s, this is just the definition of an infinitesimal transformation.  (the $\hbar$ is absorbed in the $\lambda$’s.)

Comment: @ZeroTheHero At the end, do I add the 3 equations together with the plus sign to get the full solution?  Or do I keep them separate?

Comment: @ZeroTheHero So if I use $U(\delta \lambda_1,\lambda_2,\lambda_3)$, I get $\frac{\partial \psi(\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\lambda_3 )}{\partial \lambda_1}=\delta \lambda_1 \sigma_1 |\psi(\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\lambda_3)\rangle$.

Comment: @ZeroTheHero  Is the final solution the sum of all three partial differential equations:  $\frac{\partial \psi(\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\lambda_3 )}{\partial \lambda_1}+\frac{\partial \psi(\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\lambda_3 )}{\partial \lambda_2}+\frac{\partial \psi(\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\lambda_3 )}{\partial \lambda_3}=(\delta \lambda_1 \sigma_1 + \delta \lambda_2 \sigma_2 + \delta \lambda_3 \sigma_3)|\psi(\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\lambda_3)\rangle$

Comment: @ZeroTheHero Or maybe it is the solutions to the partial differential equations that I add together at the end to get the complete solution?

Comment: You can write it as you have of course but I’m not sure where this is going.  You can also expand $\exp(i t \vec \lambda\cdot \sigma)$ for small $t$ but what do you hope to get from $(1+t (\vec \lambda\cdot\sigma))\vert \psi\rangle$?  This is just another vector differing from your initial one by an infinitesimal (presumably group) transformation.

Comment: @ZeroTheHero Or course if I put t in there and derive with respect to a variation of t I just get the Schrodinger equation; my equations is what happens when there are instead three parameters $lambda_1,\lambda_2,\lambda_3$ and I vary against all three? What is the 3-parameter equivalent to the 1-parameter Schrodinger equation?

Comment: I don’t understand what you mean by “equivalent”, but more important I don’t quite understand what this has to do with the Schrodinger equation.  What you get is a DE or PDE: is this not just Lie theory?

Comment: @ZeroTheHero I mean to say that I do know that I get a PDE if I vary with respect to a single variable $\lambda_1$. But if I want to vary against all three so that I get a solution that "grabs" the full freedom of the problem, do I then add the PDE together to get the final PDE, or what? Do I organize them as a total derivative?

Comment: sorry I don’t get it.

Comment: @ZeroTheHero It seems I am actually getting a gradient when I take all three partial derivatives, because each derivative is prefixed with a $sigma_i$. Is that possible?